# How to set different scrapy-settings for different spiders?

Tags: scrapy

I want to enable some http-proxy for some spiders, and disable them for other spiders.

Can I do something like this?

```
# settings.py
proxy_spiders = ['a1' , b2']

if spider in proxy_spider: #how to get spider name ???
    HTTP_PROXY = 'http://127.0.0.1:8123'
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
         'myproject.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
         'myproject.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410,
         'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None
    }
else:
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
         'myproject.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
         'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None
    }
```

If the code above doesn't work, is there any other suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own proxy middleware, something straightforward like this:

```
from scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware import HttpProxyMiddleware

class ConditionalProxyMiddleware(HttpProxyMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if getattr(spider, 'use_proxy', None):
            return super(ConditionalProxyMiddleware, self).process_request(request, spider)
```

Then define the attribute `use_proxy = True` in the spiders that you want to have the proxy enabled. Don't forget to disable the default proxy middleware and enable your modified one.

Answer (score 37):

a bit late, but since release 1.0.0 there is a new feature in scrapy where you can override settings per spider like this:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my_spider"
    custom_settings = {"HTTP_PROXY":'http://127.0.0.1:8123',
                       "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {'myproject.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
                                                  'myproject.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410,
                                                  'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None}}




class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "my_spider2"
        custom_settings = {"DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {'myproject.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
                                                      'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None}}
```

Comment: I get `name error "AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED" not defined`. Your snippet does not show that you're import settings.py

Answer (score 15):

There is a new and easier way to do this.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    custom_settings = {
        'SOME_SETTING': 'some value',
    }
```

I use Scrapy 1.3.1

Answer (score 8):

You can add setting.overrides within the spider.py file
Example that works:

```
from scrapy.conf import settings

settings.overrides['DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT'] = 300
```

For you, something like this should also work

```
from scrapy.conf import settings

settings.overrides['DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES'] = {
     'myproject.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
     'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None
}
```

Comment: Don't forget this before do that `from scrapy.conf import settings`

Comment: settings.overrides has been deprecated in Scrapy versions greater than 1. Using custom_settings dictionary in your spider declaration works.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use two projects rather than only one?

Let's name these two projects with `proj1` and `proj2`. In `proj1`'s `settings.py`, put these settings:

```
HTTP_PROXY = 'http://127.0.0.1:8123'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
     'myproject.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
     'myproject.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410,
     'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None
}
```

In `proj2`'s `settings.py`, put these settings:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
     'myproject.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
     'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None
}
```

Comment: That's not what the user wants to do, there are certain cases where you want multiple spiders in same project.