# Scraping dynamic content using python-Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Disclaimer: I've seen numerous other similar posts on StackOverflow and tried to do it the same way but was they don't seem to work on this website.

I'm using Python-Scrapy for getting data from koovs.com.

However, I'm not able to get the product size, which is dynamically generated. Specifically, if someone could guide me a little on getting the 'Not available' size tag from the drop-down menu on [this](http://www.koovs.com/only-onlall-stripe-ls-shirt-59554.html?from=category-651&skuid=236376) link, I'd be grateful.

I am able to get the size list statically, but doing that I only get the list of sizes but not which of them are available.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you are able to get the list of sizes, but having difficulties filtering only available sizes?

Comment: Exactly! I am able to get them statically and doing that I only get the list of sizes and not which of them are available. I'll add this to the question.

Comment: Would you be okay involving selenium?

Comment: I've never really used selenium but if it's required only to get some data and not required during the actual scraping then it's good. Could you guide me a little on how it would be used?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174330/passing-selenium-response-url-to-scrapy%20helped) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327406/how-to-set-different-scrapy-settings-for-different-spiders) helped me a lot

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can also solve it with [`ScrapyJS`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) (no need for `selenium` and a real browser):

> This library provides Scrapy+JavaScript integration using Splash.

Follow the installation instructions for [`Splash`](http://splash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) and [`ScrapyJS`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs#installation), start the splash docker container:

```
$ docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
```

Put the following settings into `settings.py`:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.59.103:8050' 

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware': 725,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapyjs.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
```

And here is your sample spider that is able to see the size availability information:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["koovs.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.koovs.com/only-onlall-stripe-ls-shirt-59554.html?from=category-651&skuid=236376',
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={
                'splash': {
                    'endpoint': 'render.html',
                    'args': {'wait': 0.5}
                }
            })

    def parse(self, response):
        for option in response.css("div.select-size select.sizeOptions option")[1:]:
            print option.xpath("text()").extract()
```

Here is what is printed on the console:

```
[u'S / 34 -- Not Available']
[u'L / 40 -- Not Available']
[u'L / 42']
```

Comment: Both great answers. Both the approaches work. I wonder if there is an advantage using one of them over the other?

Comment: @PraveshJain from what I understand, if you are okay with both the approaches, I would stick to splash - in theory, this should be faster since it doesn't involve a real browser at all. Besides, you can use this option in a non-real-screen headless environment. It is also easy to set up and there are almost no changes to the scrapy code - the key part is the middleware that scrapyjs provides. Hope that helps.

Comment: $ docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash - this command..how can i automate this command along with scrapy to scrape data using a cron job scheduler.. it obviously is not a great idea to keep  docker process running at all time..may be some sh script before i make call to reactor at scheduled time ?

Comment: @MrPandav okay, you are probably asking about docker python client, see https://github.com/docker/docker-py

Comment: @alecxe When I use the exact same solution, it times out again and again. I just change the start-url to something that is available right now in store.

Comment: Might be a silly question, but where is the settings.py file? I looked in applications, the repo area Docker created, and a few other random places I thought it might be. No idea where to find it. I'm running OS X High Sierra.

Comment: @Chelsea the settings.py should be stored in ur project directory. ProjectName > projectName > settings.py

Comment: is docker available on windows 10 and is it free?!

Comment: @alecxe it technically does use a browser: `It's a lightweight browser with an HTTP API`

Comment: Just a silly doubt - the host ip in SPLASH_URL is docker ip address right? I am trying docker ip address but it is giving me timeout

Comment: ```Retrying <GET http://172.17.0.2:8050/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2020-05-26 04:41:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-05-26 04:41:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://172.17.0.2:8050/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.```

Comment: Okay I switched to 0.0.0.0 and now response.text is having encoding problem. Should I encode it manually or am doing something wrong?

Comment: @Plasmatiger run `docker-machine ip default` in docker then change your SPLASH_URL to that, worked for me to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 10):

From what I understand, the size availability is determined dynamically in javascript being executed in the browser. Scrapy is not a browser and cannot execute javascript.

If you are okay with switching to [`selenium` browser automation tool](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org), here is a sample code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  # can be webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get('http://www.koovs.com/only-onlall-stripe-ls-shirt-59554.html?from=category-651&skuid=236376')

# wait for the select element to become visible
select_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.select-size select.sizeOptions")))

select = Select(select_element)
for option in select.options[1:]:
    print option.text

browser.quit()
```

It prints:

```
S / 34 -- Not Available
L / 40 -- Not Available
L / 42
```

Note that in place of `Firefox` you can use other webdrivers like Chrome or Safari. There is also an option to use a headless `PhantomJS` browser.

You can also combine Scrapy with Selenium if needed, see:

- [selenium with scrapy for dynamic page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page)
- [`scrapy-webdriver`](https://github.com/brandicted/scrapy-webdriver)
- [`seleniumcrawler`](https://github.com/voliveirajr/seleniumcrawler)

Answer (score 4):

I faced that problem and solved easily by following these steps

pip install splash 
pip install scrapy-splash 
pip install scrapyjs

download and install [docker-toolbox](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox)

open docker-quickterminal and enter

```
$ docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
```

**To set the SPLASH_URL check the default ip configured in the docker machine by entering 
 `$ docker-machine ip default`** (My IP was 192.168.99.100)

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.99.100:8050'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware': 725,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapyjs.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
```

That's it!

Comment: docker toolbox link is broken... :.(

Comment: @Anthony - You can get docker from here: https://www.docker.com/get-docker
The Docker Toolbox is for older Mac and Windows systems that do not meet the requirements of [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) and [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to interpret the json of the website, examples
[scrapy.readthedocs](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html) and 
[testingcan.github.io](https://testingcan.github.io/crawling-dynamically-generated-content-with-scrapy.html)

```
import scrapy
import json
class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = 'quote'
   allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
   page = 1
   start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?page=1']

   def parse(self, response):
      data = json.loads(response.text)
      for quote in data["quotes"]:
        yield {"quote": quote["text"]}
      if data["has_next"]:
          self.page += 1
          url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com/api/quotes?page={}".format(self.page)
          yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```