# scrapy: how to select only visible items

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm writing a spider with scrapy, and I find that some items are invisible by css rules, however, I want to select the visible ones only.

But xpath seems ok to those `<span style="display:none">` which style is written directly, and not ok to those `<style>.pigf{display:none}</style>` which style is written as css rule.

It seems like I should render the css so that I could filter out the invisible items correctly, but how could I render it? Is there any simpler solution?

Example html:

```
<span>
    <style>
        .pigf{display:none}.n8T-{display:inline}.pGrH{display:none}.XUYD{display:inline}.jdKj{display:none}.r7fk{display:inline}.pkO2{display:none}.EzIC{display:inline}
    </style>
    <span class="55">
        27
    </span>
    <div style="display:none">
        36
    </div>
    <span style="display:none">
        174
    </span>
    <span class="pkO2">
        174
    </span>
    <span>
    </span>
    .
    <span style="display:none">
        10
    </span>
    <span class="pkO2">
        10
    </span>
    <div style="display:none">
        10
    </div>
    <span style="display:none">
        49
    </span>
    <span class="jdKj">
        49
    </span>
    <span style="display:none">
        84
    </span>
    <span>
    </span>
    <span class="n8T-">
        115
    </span>
    <span style="display:none">
        129
    </span>
    <div style="display:none">
        129
    </div>
    <div style="display:none">
        143
    </div>
    <span style="display:none">
        151
    </span>
    <div style="display:none">
        169
    </div>
    <span>
    </span>
    .
    <span class="14">
        75
    </span>
    <span class="XUYD">
        .
    </span>
    <div style="display:none">
        23
    </div>
    <span style="display:none">
        79
    </span>
    <span style="display: inline">
        114
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: no direct solution, with `scrapy`, but you could use selenium to properly render the page (like a browser), with scrapy you just need to setup the correct xpaths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things reliable, you need something to render the HTML in - ideally a *real browser*. Look into [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) package that you can use to automate browsers. Note that a browser can also be headless, like `PhantomJS`.

`selenium` can easily [distinguish visible and invisible elements](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#element-displayedness). There is a relevant `is_displayed()` method that you may use to check the visibility. Also, if you would get a text of an element, according to the [specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#getelementtext), it would return you the visible part of the text only.

You may also get away with rendering your page in [`Splash`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash) with a help of [`scrapy-splash` middleware](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapy-splash). Example usage can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30378765/771848).

Comment: Splash doesn't let you check if element is displayed/visible