# Scrapy maintaining session

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a Scrapy spider that's trying to pick out content after i submit a form.
But the output page i get from the spider is extremely inconsistent. All the pages that i am crawling have data in them when i go through my web browser. But Scrapy goes all the way past the Form and till the result page, but most of the times does not find a result. When the resulting page actually does exist. It does however find the last page every time. So it does seem to be a problem with sessions.

Here's the code for my spider:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response


class MaharashtraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "maharashtra2"
    allowed_domains = ["mahavat.gov.in"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://mahavat.gov.in/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        return Request('http://mahavat.gov.in/Tin_Search/Tinsearch.jsp',
                       callback=self.parse_form)

    def parse_form(self, response):
        base_no = 27020000034
        no = base_no
        for i in range(100):
            yield FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                formname='f1',
                formdata={
                    "tin": "%sC" % no,
                    "pan": "",
                    "rc_no": "",
                    "fptecno": "",
                    "bptecno": "",
                    "DEALERNAME": "",
                    "Submit": "SEARCH"
                },
                callback=self.result_page)
            no += 97  # The difference between pages with content is 97

    def result_page(self, response):
        url = response.xpath('//a[@class="search-head"]/@href').extract()[0]
        url = response.urljoin(url)
        yield Request(url, callback=self.process)

    def process(self, response):
        x = response.xpath("//td/text()").extract()
        x = [x[i].strip() for i in range(1, len(x), 2)]
        print "Dealer_Name = ", x[0]
        print "Tin_Number = ", x[1]
        # inspect_response(response, self)
```

What am i doing wrong?

It seems like a session problem and NOT an ajax problem because there isn't any `XHR` request in the `post`.

Also, i kind of have a hacky way of getting over the problem, but it's super slow.

Here's the code for my hacky version.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
# from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
from VATs.items import VatsItem


class MaharashtraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "maharashtra"
    allowed_domains = ["mahavat.gov.in"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://mahavat.gov.in/',
    )

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MaharashtraSpider, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.base_no = 27020000034 - 97

    def parse(self, response):
        yield Request('http://mahavat.gov.in/Tin_Search/Tinsearch.jsp',
                      callback=self.parse_form, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_form(self, response):
        self.base_no += 97
        yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname='f1',
            formdata={
                "tin": "%sC" % self.base_no,
                "pan": "",
                "rc_no": "",
                "fptecno": "",
                "bptecno": "",
                "DEALERNAME": "",
                "Submit": "SEARCH"
            },
            callback=self.result_page)

    def result_page(self, response):
        try:
            url = response.xpath(
                '//a[@class="search-head"]/@href').extract()[0]
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.process)
        except IndexError:
            yield Request('http://mahavat.gov.in/', callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    def process(self, response):

        x = response.xpath("//td/text()").extract()
        x = [x[i].strip() for i in range(1, len(x), 2)]
        if x[0] != '':
            item = VatsItem()
            item["Dealer_Name"] = x[0]
            item["Tin_Number"] = x[1]
            item["Effective_Canceled_Date"] = x[2]
            item["Address1"] = x[3]
            item["Street_Name"] = x[4]
            item["Address2"] = x[5]
            item["Address3"] = x[6]
            item["Taluka_Name"] = x[7]
            item["District_Name"] = x[8]
            item["City_Name"] = x[9]
            item["State_Name"] = x[10]
            item["Pin_Code"] = x[11]
            item["Old_RC_No"] = x[12]
            item["Location_Name"] = x[13]
            item["Act_Name"] = x[14]
            yield item
        yield Request('http://mahavat.gov.in/', callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
        # inspect_response(response, self)
```

This one does work, but is really slow!

Could some one help me out and tell me why the first script doesn't work?

And also if there was a way to make the second script faster?

Comment: Some of the content of your crawl target is most likely dynamically loaded by javascript. That means you actually need to run those javascripts to get the content. Scrapy is only crawling the HTML frame. I faced this problem before and used selenium web driver to replace Scrapy's requests. Well, please curl the page and see if you can find the contents.

Comment: But out of the 100 pages i crawl in this script, i get a correct result for 5 pages. So its kind of doing the right stuff some times. 
Its just the `result_page()` and `process()` function that seems to be the problem. The `result_page()` is just a `GET` request once i go through with the `parse_form()`. I do have the Sessions and Cookies stored as well.

Comment: That can be a result of AJAX loading the first 5 result and anything after is triggered on demand.

Comment: But they're all individual pages generated without AJAX.

Comment: Please either curl or `pdb` to see if your HTML response really have those contents. If you insist, I can be wrong. Then I have no clue.

Comment: Hello @BoreBoar ! I have the same problem with my code. I have just started trying to do this. Would love to connect over a call and discuss. You can DM your number on my twitter: @ sunderBhiya, or share your social profile so that I can reach you.