# How can I verify that a web page is fully loaded with Scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I need to scrape a website with Scrapy that uses **AJAX Pagination**. How can I  be sure that the page is fully loaded ?

I used:

```
Download_Delay = 2
```

I need something  like `document.ready` in js.

Comment: scrapy doesn't have that, try with selenium or [Splash](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash).

Comment: you could still check which specific request was done to get the information you need and replicate that with scrapy. To debug requests I would recommend [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox.

Comment: On the Splash note I recommend this library [ScrapyJS](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida on Scrapy we can use ScrapyJs too, but i send my requests by FormRequest and i don't use scrapyJS for clicking

Comment: FormRequest doesn't use any javascript,  it only makes the post or get request on a form with the data provided. ScrapyJS loads the javascript before returning the page source which is precisely what you want

Comment: @parik the great mighty Alecxe explains best. Check out his answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975471/selenium-with-scrapy-for-dynamic-page/17979285#17979285

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345623/scraping-dynamic-content-using-python-scrapy