# Scrape data in JS Pop Up Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to know that can we scrape data of a specific field from a pop up generated on a page using Python ?  If yes, please suggest.

I am trying to scrape it, but it is not getting detected and return me an empty list. I am using Python and Beautiful soup to do the job .

Comment: Have you looked into how the popup is being generated? Is it javascript? If its javascript you probably should use phantomjs as well

Comment: Can you extract data with regular expressions from JavaScript that inserts that pop-up? Also, if data in the popup you're trying to extract is retrieved from the HTTP request, you can send that request directly and skip HTML parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `scrapy` for JS

You can also solve it with [`ScrapyJS`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs) :

`This library provides Scrapy+JavaScript integration using Splash.`

Follow the installation instructions for [`Splash`](http://splash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) and [`ScrapyJS`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs#installation), 
[READ the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345623/scraping-dynamic-content-using-python-scrapy/30378765#30378765)

> OR

You can use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html):

Follow the installation instructions [Selenium Doc](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html)