# Scrapy Spider Doesn't Return Any Information

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I'm a student, and for a project I'm collecting information on brands. I found this website called Kit: [Kit Page](https://kit.com/brands?page=1) that I want to scrape for brands. It has almost 500 pages, and I wrote a Scrapy Spider in Python 3 that go through each of the pages and copies the list to a dictionary, but I can't figure out the xpath or css to actually get the list info. Here's my items.py:

```
import scrapy

class KitcreatorwebscraperItem(scrapy.Item):
    creator = scrapy.Field()
```

and here's my spider:

```
import scrapy

class KitCreatorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "kitCreators"
    pageNumber = 1

    start_urls = [
        'https://kit.com/brands?page=1',
    ]

    while pageNumber <= 478:
        newUrl = "https://kit.com/brands?page=" + str(pageNumber)
        start_urls.append(newUrl)
        pageNumber += 1

    def parse(self, response):
        for li in response.xpath('//div[@class="section group"][0]'):
```

It runs successfully, but I have been unable to write an xpath that gets the data I need. What path is necessary, and how do I implement that in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below `Xpath` to extract brand names:

```
//a[@class="brandsView-list-item-link ng-binding"]/text()
```

P.S. I would suggest you not to create the list of URLs. It seem to be redundant piece of code. Instead you might use `for` loop like:

```
for page_number in range(479):
    url = "https://kit.com/brands?page=%s" % page_number
    ...handle current page source...
```

*Update*

[You can try](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/) [`Selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html) + [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) to get required data from dynamic content:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
brands_list = []

for page in range(1, 480):
    driver.get("https://kit.com/brands?page=%s" % page)
    [brands_list.append(brand.text) for brand in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="brandsView-list-item-link ng-binding"]')]

print(brands_list)
```

Comment: Hi Andersson, when I plug this in in this form: **def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            "company":response.xpath('//a[@class="brandsView-list-item-link ng-binding"]/text()')
        }**            I am still met with an empty list as the output. Could you provide more info on implementation or placement of this path in the code?

Comment: This is because page content is dynamic and you cannot get it simply with `scrapy`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345623/scraping-dynamic-content-using-python-scrapy)

Comment: I have been unsuccessful in implementing your attached method thus far, but I'll keep trying. If you have any recommendations or suggestions, they are absolutely welcome. Thanks!