# Can't figure out why my Scrapy script isn't working

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://go.twitch.tv/directory']
def parse(self, response):
    for title in response.css('body'):
        yield {'title': title.css('h3.tw-box-art-card__title::text').extract()}

    for next_page in response.css('a::attr(href)'):
        yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse)
```

It just crawls and scrapes https://go.twitch.tv/directory but doesn't put out any titles.

I'm new to Python so the problem is probably really obvious but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Why do you expect your code to put out any titles?

Comment: Because of the parse function and the command "scrapy crawl test -o test.csv that I use to run the script

Comment: Your code is badly indented. Fix it and you may find it helpful.

Comment: @Massaxe Is `parse` actually being called or not?

Comment: @Massaxe , the content of that webpage is generated dynamically so to catch that you need to use any browser simulator like selenium.

Comment: I'm like 99% sure that the code works because if I change all the selectors and so on to use it on Wikipedia it works perfectly. I think I just have to get good.

Comment: Oooooh okay I'll look it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shahin mentioned, page generated dynamically and you can't parse it, without something like selenium or splash. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30345623/7877686).

**Also there is another way**: You can make some searches in how request generated which will give you needed data.

For example, when page loaded or when you go to the bottom, there is request to the https://gql.twitch.tv/gql with some data, look at the image below:
[image: Request image]

This is request will return you json with directory games description:[image: request response data]
So, i think that you need just find out how request data build and make request not the `twitch.tv/directory`, but the `gql.twitch.tv/gql` and parse response which in json format.

How to make request with body read [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) (there is body argument)