# Unable to scrape hidden content in twitter

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have recently posted a question about how to login to twitter using requests library. Finally, I got the solution for that and another problem i am facing is that i am able to scrape only visible content in the page. How to scrape dynamically loaded content in that page?

**Note:** I am not using selenium. Please provide any other means to do this.

How to load dynamic content and then scrape it?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345623/scraping-dynamic-content-using-python-scrapy) solution

Comment: actually we can scrape dynamic content simply using requests and session(get and post). Instead of using webdrivers we can do in this way.

Comment: OK. So what is the point of your question?

Comment: I am unable to get hidden content using requests. I am unable to understand what parameters have to be used for that. So I want your help in finding the parameters

Comment: If you are _not using selenium_ why is `selenium` tagged in your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sorry to post question in this way, i will improve my skills in asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using something like Selenium or another browser (headless or otherwise) which will actually run the JavaScript in a normal-ish manner, the only other method would be to manually reverse engineer the JavaScript, see what kind of calls it's making, and make them yourself directly.

There wouldn't be any other kind of "one-size-fits-all" solution.

Comment: Can you help me with this? how to look for parameters causing javascipt loading and how to use them?

Comment: Sorry, but that isn't really what SO is for. It's for help with your own code, not reverse engineering others. If you aren't able to do it, you might look to a freelancer to write some code for you (for pay, of course).

Comment: Finally I understood how to scrape it.