# Copying the xpath from Instagram inspect (using chrome) returns an empty list

Tags: xpath, scrapy, instagram

So I would go to an instagram account, say, https://www.instagram.com/foodie/ to copy its xpath that gives me the number of posts, number of followers, and number of following.

I would then run the command this command on a scrapy shell:

> response.xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/header/section/ul')

to grab the elements on that list but scrapy keeps returning an empty list. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scraping dynamic content using python-Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345623/scraping-dynamic-content-using-python-scrapy)

Comment: use view(response) command, and then check if the site is dynamic or the elements are different.

Comment: View page source and see what you get before browser executes JS. Also `view(response)` from scrapy shell as @la_vie_est_belle said.

Comment: Yup. Scrapy returns True. The command 
response.xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]') 
returns something but after including /section, it returns an empty list when it should return it's children. Any thoughts?

Comment: The page structure you see might be different than that the scrapy spider “sees”, and that’s why you need view(response) command to check what the spider “sees”.

Answer (score 1):

This site is a Single Page Application (SPA) so it's javascript that render DOM is not rendered yet at the time your downloader working.

When you use `view(response)` the javascript that your downloader collected can continue render by your browser, so you can see the page with DOM rendered (but can't interacting with Site API). You can look at your downloaded content via `response.text` and saw that!

In this case, you can apply selenium + phantomjs to making a rendered page for your spider!

Another trick: You can use regular expression to select the JSON part of Script, parse it to JSON obj and select your correspond attribute value (number of post, following, ...) from script!