# passing selenium response url to scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am learning Python and am trying to scrape this [page](http://www.cppcc.gov.cn/CMS/icms/project1/cppcc/wylibary/wjWeiYuanList.jsp) for a specific value on the dropdown menu. After that I need to click each item on the resulted table to retrieve the specific information.  I am able to select the item and retrieve the information on the webdriver. But I do not know how to pass the response url to the crawlspider.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.cppcc.gov.cn/CMS/icms/project1/cppcc/wylibary/wjWeiYuanList.jsp')
more_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
     EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, '_button_select'))
            )  
more_btn.click()

## select specific value from the dropdown
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#tabJcwyxt_jiebie >     option[value='teyaoxgrs']").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#tabJcwyxt_jieci > option[value='d11jie']").click()
search2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input_a2')
search2.click()
time.sleep(5)

## convert html to "nice format"
text_html=driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
html_str=str(text_html)

## this is a hack that initiates a "TextResponse" object (taken from the Scrapy module)
resp_for_scrapy=TextResponse('none',200,{},html_str,[],None)

## convert html to "nice format"
text_html=driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
html_str=str(text_html)

resp_for_scrapy=TextResponse('none',200,{},html_str,[],None)
```

So this is where I am stuck. I was able to query using the above code. But How can I pass **resp_for_scrapy** to the **crawlspider**? I put **resp_for_scrapy** in place of **item** but that didn't work.

```
## spider 
class ProfileSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'pccprofile2'
allowed_domains = ['cppcc.gov.cn']
start_urls = ['http://www.cppcc.gov.cn/CMS/icms/project1/cppcc/wylibary/wjWeiYuanList.jsp']    

def parse(self, resp_for_scrapy):

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(resp_for_scrapy)
    for post in resp_for_scrapy.xpath('//div[@class="table"]//ul//li'):
        items = []
        item = Ppcprofile2Item()
        item ["name"] = hxs.select("//h1/text()").extract()
        item ["title"] = hxs.select("//div[@id='contentbody']//tr//td//text()").extract()
        items.append(item)

    ##click next page      
    while True:
        next = self.driver.findElement(By.linkText("下一页"))
        try:
            next.click()
        except:
            break

    return(items)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!!

**EDITS** I included a middleware class to select from the dropdown before the spider class. But now there is no error and no result.

```
class JSMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
         driver.get('http://www.cppcc.gov.cn/CMS/icms/project1/cppcc/wylibary/wjWeiYuanList.jsp')


    # select from the dropdown
        more_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, '_button_select'))
                )
        more_btn.click()


        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#tabJcwyxt_jiebie > option[value='teyaoxgrs']").click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("select#tabJcwyxt_jieci > option[value='d11jie']").click()
        search2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('input_a2')
        search2.click()
        time.sleep(5)

        #get the response 
        body = driver.page_source
        return HtmlResponse(driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)



class ProfileSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'pccprofile2'
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=("//div[@class='table']")), callback='parse_item')]  

    def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    items = []
    item = Ppcprofile2Item()
    item ["name"] = hxs.select("//h1/text()").extract()
    item ["title"] = hxs.select("//div[@id='contentbody']//tr//td//text()").extract()
    items.append(item)

    #click next page      
    while True:
        next = response.findElement(By.linkText("下一页"))
        try:
            next.click()
        except:
            break

    return(items)
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174330/passing-selenium-response-url-to-scrapy%20helped) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327406/how-to-set-different-scrapy-settings-for-different-spiders) helped me a lot

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [Downloader Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) to catch selenium-required pages *before* you process them regularly with Scrapy:

> The downloader middleware is a framework of hooks into Scrapy’s request/response processing. It’s a light, low-level system for globally altering Scrapy’s requests and responses.

Here's a very basic example using PhantomJS:

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from selenium import webdriver

class JSMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        driver.get(request.url)

        body = driver.page_source
        return HtmlResponse(driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
```

Once you return that `HtmlResponse` (or a `TextResponse` if that's what you really want), Scrapy will cease processing downloaders and drop into the spider's `parse` method:

> If it returns a Response object, Scrapy won’t bother calling any other
>   process_request() or process_exception() methods, or the appropriate
>   download function; it’ll return that response. The process_response()
>   methods of installed middleware is always called on every response.

In this case, you can continue to use your spider's `parse` method as you normally would with HTML, except that the JS on the page has already been executed.

**Tip: Since the Downloader Middleware's `process_request` method accepts the spider as an argument, you can add a conditional in the spider to check whether you need to process JS at all, and that will let you handle both JS and non-JS pages with the exact same spider class.**

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the suggestion. I did what you suggested by including a JSMiddleware class before the CrawlSpider class. And within the middleware class, I pasted the code of which I select from the dropdown and click. There was no result and no error returned either.  Please see the edits above.

Comment: Your edit doesn't include a `return` statement. Make sure you're returning a response from the middleware.

Comment: I had the `return` statement. i realized just now I got an error `from scrapy.http import HttpResponse  ImportError: cannot import name HttpResponse ` i will see if this is the issue...

Comment: AH, that's my fault! It should be `HtmlResponse`, not `HttpResponse`. I'll make that edit.

Comment: still no luck. no error and result. This is the console output: `
2015-07-02 10:33:28-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-07-02 10:33:28-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware`

Comment: i might have been getting confused with the middlewares structure. I will post another question on that.  thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

Here is a middleware for Scrapy and Selenium

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.utils.python import to_bytes
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy import signals


class SeleniumMiddleware(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        middleware = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return middleware

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['driver'] = self.driver  # to access driver from response
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        body = to_bytes(self.driver.page_source)  # body must be of type bytes 
        return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()
```

Also need to add in `settings.py`

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'youproject.middlewares.selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 200
}
```

Decide weather its `200` or something else based on [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES_BASE).

**Update** *firefox headless mode with scrapy and selenium*

If you want to run firefox in headless mode then install [xvfb](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)

```
sudo apt-get install -y xvfb
```

and [PyVirtualDisplay](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay)

```
sudo pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

and use this middleware

```
from shutil import which

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

settings = get_project_settings()

HEADLESS = True


class SeleniumMiddleware(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        middleware = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(middleware.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return middleware

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        request.meta['driver'] = self.driver
        body = str.encode(self.driver.page_source)
        return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        if HEADLESS:
            self.display = Display(visible=0, size=(1280, 1024))
            self.display.start()
        binary = FirefoxBinary(settings.get('FIREFOX_EXE') or which('firefox'))
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()
        if HEADLESS:
            self.display.stop()
```

where `settings.py` contains

```
FIREFOX_EXE = '/path/to/firefox.exe'
```

The problem is that some versions of firefox don't work with selenium.
To solve this problem you can download firefox version 47.0.1 (this version works flawlessly) from [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) then extract it and put it inside your selenium project. Afterwards modify firefox path as

```
FIREFOX_EXE = '/path/to/your/scrapyproject/firefox/firefox.exe'
```

Comment: what does the `from_crawler` function do? what does the `cls` parameter represent and what is it that the statements in the function do?