# Integrating Selenium with Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

Is there any way to effectively integrate Selenium into Scrapy for it's page rendering capabilities (in order to generate screenshots)?

A lot of solutions I've seen just throw a Scrapy request/response URL at WebDriver *after* Scrapy's already processed the request, and then just works off that.  This creates twice as many requests, fails in many ways (sites requiring logins, sites with dynamic or pseudo-random content, etc.), and invalidates many extensions/middleware.

Is there any "good" way of getting the two to work together?  Is there a better way for generating screenshots of the content I'm scraping?

Answer (score 6):

Use Scrapy's [Downloader Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html). See my answer on another question for a simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31186730/639806

Comment: I've looked at this, and while it does fix one of the issues (doubling up on requests), it bypasses many features Scrapy provides.  It discard user-agent configuration, proxy configurations, headers, and offers zero persistence between calls (no sessions/cookies). Furthermore, it's impossible to submit POST requests in Selenium, so things like FormRequests will break or have very unexpected results.

Comment: It does bypass those things. It's a very simple example, but a lot of those things can be duplicated in Selenium (such as cookies, headers and user-agent string). In fact, most of that info you can pull using the request information that's available as an arg to the `process_request` method. Also, you won't need to POST through Selenium. No reason you can't do that through Scrapy in `parse` after pulling the Selenium response.

Comment: Wouldn't the FormRequest be 'hijacked' by the Selenium Downloader Middleware as it passed through, and then processed as a driver.get(url)" by Selenium?  How could this be prevented?

Comment: Use a conditional (e.g., `if should_process_js(request):`), and just return `return request` to continue processing normally if whatever conditions are false (such as the request being a POST, or whatever you decide).

Comment: I've worked on this and found other issues, that I was curious if you had any thoughts on.  Returning an HtmlResponse doesn't fire off the response_downloaded signal, and anything relying on it breaks (such as throttling).  CustomHeaders, most importantly "Referer" cannot be manually set on WebDriver.