# Scrapy Basic Crawler not working?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I recently just started trying out Scrapy for a project, and I got very much confused with the various older syntaxes (SgmlLinkExtractor etc.) but I somehow managed to put together what I thought was legible code which made sense to me. However, this does not traverse through every page in the website, instead only goes to the start_urls page and doesn't produce the output file. Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

```
import scrapy
import csv
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class RLSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "RL"
    allowed_domains='ralphlauren.com/product/'
    start_urls=[
        'http://www.ralphlauren.com/'
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(),callback="parse_item",follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract_first()
        price = response.xpath('//span[@class="reg-price"]/span/text()').extract_first()
        image=response.xpath('//input[@name="enh_0"]/@value').extract_first()
        print("Rules=",rules)
        tup=(name,price,image)
        csvF=open('data.csv','w')
        csvWrite = csv.writer(csvF)
        csvWrite.writerow(tup)
        return []
    def parse(self,response):
        pass
```

I'm trying to extract data from the website and write it into a csv file from all pages coming under /product/

Here are the logs :

```
2016-12-07 19:46:49 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.2 started (bot: P35Crawler)
2016-12-07 19:46:49 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'P35Crawler
', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'P35Crawler.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['P35Crawler.spid
ers']}
2016-12-07 19:46:49 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2016-12-07 19:46:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-12-07 19:46:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-12-07 19:46:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-12-07 19:46:50 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-12-07 19:46:50 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 i
tems (at 0 items/min)
2016-12-07 19:46:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-12-07 19:46:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.ralphla
uren.com/home/index.jsp?ab=Geo_iIN_rUS_dUS> from <GET http://www.ralphlauren.com
/>
2016-12-07 19:46:51 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.ralphlauren.co
m/home/index.jsp?ab=Geo_iIN_rUS_dUS> (referer: None)
2016-12-07 19:46:51 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-12-07 19:46:51 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 497,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 20766,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 7, 14, 16, 51, 973406),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 7, 14, 16, 50, 287464)}
2016-12-07 19:46:51 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: check your logs, I assume urls are being filtered because of `allowed_domains`, remove that.

Comment: @eLRuLL Hi, thanks for the reply. Posted the log. Tried commenting out allowed_domains but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't overwrite the `parse()` method with an empty one. So just remove the declaration of that method. Please, let me know if this helps.

**UPDATE**

Regarding your comment on parsing `JS` with `scrapy`, there are different ways to do that. You need a browser to parse `JS`. Let's say you would want to try `Firefox` and control it with `Selenium`.

The best way IMO is to implement a download handler, as I explain on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40301303/1204332). You could, otherwise, implement a `downloader middleware`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174330/passing-selenium-response-url-to-scrapy/31186730#31186730). The `middleware` has some downsides compared to the `handler`, as the `download handler` would allow you to use the default `cache`, `retry`, etc.

After you get the basic script working with `Firefox`, you can then switch to `PhantomJS` by changing just a few lines. `PhantomJS` is a headless browser, which means that it doesn't need to load all the browser interface. So it's much faster.

Other solutions include using `Docker` with `Splash`, but I ended up considering this an overkill, as you need to run a `VM` just to control the browser.

So summing up, the best solution is to implement a `download handler` that makes use of `Selenium` and `PhantomJS`.

Comment: Hi, thanks that worked, but now with allowed_domains restricted to ralphlauren.com , everything is getting filtered out and still only crawling the first website.

Comment: Okay I noticed most of the links I needed are in the JavaScript part of the website, how do I crawl through those?