# Scrapy + Selenium issue

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the website of a prominent UK retailer, using both Selenium and Scrapy (see code below). I'm getting a `[scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing` and have no idea what else to do (been at it for three hours or so). Thank you for all your support!

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from nl_scrape.items import NlScrapeItem
import time

class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "product_spider"
    allowed_domains = ['newlook.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/c/uk-womens-clothing?comp=NavigationBar%7Cmn%7Cwomens%7Cclothing#/?q=:relevance&page=1&sort=relevance&content=false']

def __init__(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
    self.driver.set_window_size(800,600)
    time.sleep(4)

def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(4)

    # Collect products
    products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('plp-item ng-scope')

    # Iterate over products; extract data and append individual features to NlScrapeItem
    for item in products:

        # Pull features
        desc = item.find_element_by_class_name('product-item__name link--nounderline ng-binding').text
        href = item.find_element_by_class_name('plp-carousel__img-link ng-scope').get_attribute('href')

        # Price Symbol removal and integer conversion
        priceString = item.find_element_by_class_name('price ng-binding').text
        priceInt = priceString.split('£')[1]
        price = float(priceInt)

        # Generate a product identifier
        identifier = href.split('/p/')[1].split('?comp')[0]
        identifier = int(identifier)

        # datetime
        dt = date.today()
        dt = dt.isoformat()

        # NlScrapeItem
        item = NlScrapeItem()

        # Append product to NlScrapeItem
        item['id'] = identifier
        item['href'] = href
        item['description'] = desc
        item['price'] = price
        item['firstSighted'] = dt
        item['lastSighted'] = dt
        yield item

    self.driver.close()
```

> 2017-08-26 15:48:38 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing http://www.newlook.com/uk/womens/clothing/c/uk-womens-clothing?comp=NavigationBar%7Cmn%7Cwomens%7Cclothing#/?q=:relevance&page=1&sort=relevance&content=false> (referer: None)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/username/Documents/nl_scraping/nl_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
>       current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
>     File "/Users/username/Documents/nl_scraping/nl_scrape/nl_scrape/spiders/product_spider.py", line 18, in parse
>       products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('plp-item ng-scope')
>   NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

Comment: try using,  products = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('plp-item ng-scope') and lets see if it works

Comment: @Kapil: no luck unfortunately :( _ERROR: Spider error processing_ prevails

Comment: did atleast your safari browser start?

Comment: @Kapil: Yes it does - I previously played around with selenium in the console just to get a sense of it and every line of code works individually - just the scrapy implementation is struggling. Do you have any thoughts on using a middleware? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174330/passing-selenium-response-url-to-scrapy) - I was thinking of the answer for this question.

Comment: @Kapil: Thank you very much for all your help! works now thanks to the workaround below - your thinking was obviously extremely close given Tarun's answer is working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your code has two issues

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(4)

    # Collect products
    products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('plp-item ng-scope')
```

Very conveniently you changed `self.driver` to just `driver`. Doesn't work that way. You should add at the top of the function

```
def parse(self, response):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(4)

    # Collect products
    products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('plp-item ng-scope')
```

Next you have used `self.driver.close()` at the end of the function. So you will close the browser once you process one url. That is wrong. So remove that line.

Comment: that was it - thank you very much - I can't up vote because my reputation is still too low!

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani , although this is not my thread, I would be very happy if i could know where to put that line `self.driver.close()`. Thanks.

Comment: @Shahin, you would need to listen to the `spider_closed` signal and execute the code over there. There is a simple example on how to hook to that code here https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. You should have +1 from my end.

Comment: @ Tarun Lalwani, looks like I found a solution as to how I could close the webdriver when it is done. Just putting this after init method `def __del__(self):self.driver.close()` will do the trick.

Comment: @Shahin, thanks for sharing this. Will keep that solution in mind